# Visualize GBP against.. nothing

Tags: foreign-exchange

How can I see GBP, not compared to another currency, but just the standalone trend of GBP over time?
I’m interested in the history of the currency related to UK political events (but untainted by the political events of some other country (eg USD)).

Comment: You should probably clarify then exactly what kind of trend you are looking for. GBP, if not compared to other currencies, is always worth 1. 1 GBP = 1 GBP at all times. Maybe what you are looking for is purchasing power / inflation ?

Comment: One GBP is always worth one GBP because that's the currency denomination.  You either have to compare it to other currencies or to itself over time  (inflation).

Comment: https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices

Comment: I would compare GBP to a basket of currencies such as here: https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/bank-of-england-spot/historical-effective-exchange-rates/GBP-history . In the multi-year charts, you can see an obvious dip that started around June 2016 (Brexit vote).

Answer (score 10):

You can't measure something without a yardstick to measure it by.

Remember that there's pretty much only one thing you can do with currency: buy something. The value of a currency **is** its ability to buy other things. So:

- If you're interested in the pound's ability to buy other currencies, look at exchange rates.
- If you're interested in the pound's ability to buy precious metals, look at the prices of precious metals in GBP.
- If you're interested in the pound's ability to buy consumer goods, look at the UK's Consumer Price Index.
- If you're interested in the pound's ability to buy labor, look at British wage statistics.

But if you're interested in the pound's standalone value, then you're out of luck... because the pound doesn't *have* any standalone value.

Comment: The pound *does* have standalone value: it is worth exactly one pound. Of course it is not of much help to the OP :-). Nice answer.